# wxPython, Disabling buttons?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a list of buttons and I have made a loop to find out what button is pressed, then disable that button on click.

Here is the snippet of code:

```
    def change(self,event):
        self.Disable()


    for i in enumerate(file_pool):
        self.button_pool.append(wx.Button(self.sizer, -1, i[1], pos=(20, i[0]*45),size=(200,40))) #this would create the list of buttons
    for i in self.button_pool:
        i.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.change) #bind each button
```

However, this will Disable every widget, not just the pressed button. How can I only disable the clicked button?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can get your object from the event:

```
def change(self, event):
    myobject = event.GetEventObject()
    myobject.Disable()
```

Comment: is there a way, to enable the other buttons once one button is pressed?

Comment: You can enable all of them getting them from your list of buttons in a loop but checking first `if myobject == item_from_list`